# How do I get window attributes in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
self.attributes("-alpha", Alpha)
```

How do I get window attributes in Tkinter? Currently I wan't my program to get the value of **Alpha**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an earlier question you asked about transparency I gave an example that gets the alpha value for a window. See [Having trouble with Tkinter transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399882/having-trouble-with-tkinter-transparency)